# I am receiving an error from my JS code dealing with a sort function

Tags: javascript, function

So I have this code that I'm using for a class, but whenever I run it, nothing shows in the browser and instead under the Console I get an error that says that data.sort is not a function.

Here is the code in its entirety.

```
// Use d3 to read the JSON file.
// The data from the JSON file is arbitrarily named importedData as the argument.
d3.json("data/data.json").then((importedData) => {
  // console.log(importedData);
  var data = importedData;

  // Sort the data array by using the greekSearchResults value.
  data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(b.greekSearchResults) - parseFloat(a.greekSearchResults);
  });

  // Slice the first 10 objects for plotting.
  data = data.slice(0, 10);

  // Reverse the array because of the Plotly defaults.
  data = data.reverse();

  // Trace1 for the Greek data.
  var trace1 = {
    x: data.map(row => row.greekSearchResults),
    y: data.map(row => row.greekName),
    text: data.map(row => row.greekName),
    name: "Greek",
    type: "bar",
    orientation: "h"
  };

  // Data
  var chartData = [trace1];

  // Apply the group bar mode to the layout.
  var layout = {
    title: "Greek gods search results",
    margin: {
      l: 100,
      r: 100,
      t: 100,
      b: 100
    }
  };

  // Render the plot to the div tag with the id of "plot".
  Plotly.newPlot("plot", chartData, layout);
});
```

Comment: Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).
Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser.
What is `data`? It’s clearly not an Array, so what else is it? What does the `console.log(importedData);` reveal?

Comment: Is `importedData` being deserialized?

Comment: I'll be honest, this entire thing was done for a class but the code was done by someone else who works for the company.  I'm just trying to make this work and I'm still a novice with JS.

Comment: The JS file is supposed to be reading a JSON file and the data.sort is supposed to sort the data which is then spit out as a Plotly diagram. But nothing shows up when I run the HTML file.

Comment: It won't have any output since the line `data.sort(function(a, b) {` throws an error, the rest of the code isn't executed. It's probably worth uncommenting `console.log(importedData);` to see if it's pulling any data at all.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` is an array method. my guess is that the importedData variable isn't an array, hence you get that error. if you wish to use it, make sure to create an array from the data response.

`sort` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort